# Phone Number in Developer Story

Tags: support, developer-story

When I print the developer story or save it to PDF, a phone number appears on the upper right corner, just below the location.

**Where does the phone number come from and how can it be changed?**

Oddly it does not seem to appear anywhere other than the print view. Most importantly though, it is wrong and that number may eventually be allocated to someone else.

Comment: I do not see a phone number in the PDF.

Comment: You probably want to use a different PDF printer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The phone number is located under your [Settings > Job Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current). You should be able to make the edit there.

Comment: This is a real pain in the butt!!

Comment: Yeah took me ages to find it. Finally found it at Edit Profile & Settings Tab - Job Preferences, scroll to the bottom and found Contact Information

Comment: I was looking on Dev Story where to specify phone number, wanted it to show on PDF, but I would have never guessed that it was on different section on site!  come on SO.......